# powershell avoid error message copy-item for an existing folder

Tags: powershell

I tried with -force but I still get error message

Copy-Item : An item with the specified name C:\folder2 already
exists.

```
Copy-Item 'c:\folder1' -Destination 'c:\folder2' -force
```

Comment: Can you paste the error? `$Error[0]`

Comment: It works for me.  But this won't copy any files in folder1.  And on second run it will create folder1 inside folder2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the destination folder first and then copy everything inside the source folder by adding `\*` to the path:

```
# first create the destination folder if it does not already exist
$null = New-Item -Path 'c:\folder2' -ItemType Directory -Force
# then copy all from the source folder to the destination
Copy-Item -Path 'c:\folder1\*' -Destination 'c:\folder2' -Recurse -Force
```

By using switch `-Force` on the New-Item command, the cmdlet returns either the object of a newly created folder **or** the object of an existing folder.
In both cases, we do not need that output, so we'll ignore it using `$null =`